# get location without google play services -android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I know some phones do not preinstall google play sevice.  I want to ask is there possible way to get location without Google Play Services , just use LocationManager. Not LocationClient.

Answer (score 23):

you can use LocationManager

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: @user2506173 this has nothing to do with maps they are completely independant

Comment: you can get latitude and longtitude and with that values show that place in the map

Comment: V1 maps are still supported, if you already got a key for your application, but no new Google Maps V1 keys are generated anymore, which will force new application to use V2.

Answer (score 2):

USe a LocationManager and set the appropriate provider, GPS or NETWORK.
you can get periodic updates or a single update using the requestLocationUpdates() and the getLastKnownLocation() methods respectively.
Lastly, get a Location object and retrieve the latitude, longitude by calling the required methods on the Location object.