# Do apps on Android need to be connected to Google Play to access location data?

Tags: android, location, google-play

Im new to the forum. Ive searched it, but not found any conclusive answers to my question.

Im building a location based app. Ive just started it. Im reading about how to get location based data. I am aware that not everyone uses GooglePlay. My first question is:

Do you need to be connected to Google Play to access the location services of your device?

[get location without google play services -android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726728/get-location-without-google-play-services-android)

The above thread mentions using LocationManager without using LocationClient, (Im still getting to grips with these terms!)

I want my app to be as accessible as possible to all users, hence the question.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 0):

You need google Play to access Google Maps API. If you want to be accessible to all users, it's okay because you might be publishing it on Google Play and almost every users have Google Play adjusted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean by every user has GooglePay adjusted?

Comment: He means every user (an overwhelming percentage, at least) has Google Play _installed_.

Comment: When you buy an Android the first thing you have to set is the Google Play. So, if you are making an app, you will probably publish on Google Play (old Google Market). To download, the users need to have the google play, so yes, your application will work well

Comment: Thank you very much for your time guys, that's going to help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Google Play to receive location updates, however it may be required if you'd like to use i.e. Fusy Location Provider (which is part of Google Play Services).