# Are Google Play Services required to find the current gps location on an Android phone?

Tags: android

I've found two sources on retrieving the GPS location of an andriod phone, one from the Google Website:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#top

and one from here:

[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)

They both describe different steps. I'm not sure which one to follow, unfortunately the Android Emulator doesn't seem to come with Google Play installed, so I want to go with the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use LocationManager to getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Flow), [without Play services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726728/get-location-without-google-play-services-android).

Answer (score 0):

No they aren't. Google services provide support for A-GPS assisted with Wifi which can get a location fix faster than just GPS or GPS+Mobile network.

Answer (score 0):

Well Emulator device can get location co-ordinates but manually by ddms device manager,
 And yes there are two way get location co-ordinates. One by android native and other by google play servives library. second one has its own issues. its works with proper version of google play services installed on the device. I prefer better use first one android by using simple location manager class.