# get user location not working on android devices without google play services

Tags: android, dictionary, mapbox

I have an issue with huawei devices and all devices without google play services
What should I do if I want to get user location from these devices?

Comment: The gps chip gives does not give info  without those services? Hard to believe.

Comment: Can you describe the issue in more detail than "not working"?  What happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LocationManager with GPS or NETWORK provider.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Reference: [get location without google play services -android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726728/get-location-without-google-play-services-android)